# Sequelize does not return a value within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize to connect to Azure SQL database from Node.js. The sequelize query module is placed within a function, and the matched boolean variable is returned to the main script (app.js).

Sequelize along with the function are part of (app_functions.js)

The code snippets are pasted below:

**app_functions.js**

```
function loginIds(email_id) {
  var is_matched = false;

  sequelize.query("SELECT emailid FROM user_data where emailid='" + email_id + "'", {
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      console.log('DB email id is: ' + result[0].emailid);

      if (result[0].emailid != '') {
        console.log('True block');
        is_matched = true;
      } else {
        is_matched = false;
      }
    })

  return is_matched;
}
```

**app.js**

```
// Import app_functions.js
var fs = require('fs');
eval(fs.readFileSync('app_functions.js').toString());

console.log("Matched value is: "+ loginIds('xyz@gmail.com'));
```

**Output**

```
Matched value is: false
Executing (default): SELECT emailid FROM user_data where emailid='xyz@gmail.com'
[ { emailid: 'xyz@gmail.com' } ]
DB email id is: xyz@gmail.com
True block
```

The function returns `false`, although the `True block`, inside `if` condition is executed.
Also note that, the function returns the value first and then executes the definition.

**How to return the correct `true` value from the function containing sequelize?**

Comment: 2nd solution does not work.with `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning a promise from `loginIds` and then `.then`ning the promise in `app.js`:

```
function loginIds(email_id) {
  var is_matched = false;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  sequelize.query("SELECT emailid FROM user_data where emailid='" + email_id + "'", {
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      console.log('DB email id is: ' + result[0].emailid);

      if (result[0].emailid != '') {
        console.log('True block');
        is_matched = true;
      } else {
        is_matched = false;
      }
      resolve(is_matched);
    })
  })   // Closing of Promise block
}
```

app.js:

```
loginIds('xyz@gmail.com')
  .then((match) => {
    console.log("Matched value is: "+ match);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As `sequelize.query` is `async` behaviour and returns promise so you can do it like :

**Without extra promise :**

```
function loginIds(email_id) {
    var is_matched = false;

    return sequelize.query("SELECT emailid FROM user_data where emailid='" + email_id + "'", {
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log('DB email id is: ' + result[0].emailid);

        if (result[0].emailid != '') {
            console.log('True block');
            is_matched = true;
        } else {
            is_matched = false;
        }
        return is_matched;
    });
}

loginIds('xyz@gmail.com').then((match) => {
    console.log("Matched value is: "+ match);
});
```